# WordPress Database Script Name

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am asking this question because I have not found an answer on the web.  I would like to know the name of the script in WordPress that is responsible for ceating the tables for the WordPress database. I undestand that you have to pass connection information into wp-config.php, however I could not find the .sql script that is responsible for creating the tables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/wp-admin/wp-install.php` uses `/wp-includes/wp-db.php`